# Can you identify the shower brand by these handles?

Tags: shower, faucet, valve

I need to change my shower handle stems since they are semi-broken. The handles do not include any signs or logos for who the manufacturer is.

Any ideas how I can find out or even find a similar company?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There might be identifying markings on the side of the cartridge that you can see after taking it out. If that doesn't help, try taking it to a plumbing supply store (not necessarily a BigBox) if possible. Chances are they'll recognize it.

Comment: ^^^ +1  Take it to a "real" plumbing store.  The guy there will look at it and say "Oh yeah, that's a Flibberjabin Concroxitoa valve, part number 39AA-1"  or whatever.   And then after he tells you that, buy it from him instead of Amazon because his experience is worth something.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this cartridge identification guide.

https://content.interlinebrands.com/product/document/10145/133938_Brochure.pdf

Another one here:

https://www.jonesstephens.com/files/Downloads/02573-03-Repair-Parts-Catalog.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You may find a match if you use Google Lens... Download the Google Search Engine App (logo is a G) if you don't have it already > look at the search bar and you'll see two icons, one that looks like a camera - tap that one > take a picture with it and if there is anything out there for sale that looks like what you have, you'll find it.

Comment: Or it could be from an RV in which case none of the above is going to help identify it. You are best off, imho, replacing the entire valve with a current anti-scald model.