# What brand is this shower stem?

Tags: shower

Anybody help me with name brand these shower stems are?

[image]

Comment: Were there any markings on the tap handle itself?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: how many notches on the spline?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/238186/97214

Comment: Following on @FreshCodemonger, there a number of broach types.  The details on yours may help direct you to a specific manufacturer. Here are some additional resources for you: https://www.danco.com/how-to-guide/how-to-match-your-broach-with-the-stem-finder-tool/ https://bonnetsandstems.com/?page_id=105